# How to view release notes / changelog with pacman

Tags: archlinux

Like many fellow archers, I use `pacman` to update my software each day.
Often there are updates like this:

```
foo-1.1 ---> foo.1.2
```

I wonder if there's a way to see what has been updated from `foo-1.1` to `foo-1.2` or release notes explaining bug fixes or new features etc.
Something like `pacman -Log foo`.

Comment: found it:https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=70557

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the manual:

```
QUERY OPTIONS
   -c, --changelog
       View the ChangeLog of a package. Not every package will provide one but it will be shown if available.
```

So, if you wanted the changelog for the vim package, for example, you would do: `pacman -Qc vim`.

Comment: Yep, I've found that some don't have the change logs. I have a feeling it's mostly luck and maybe the popularity of the package.

Comment: @RyanA. ;) right *popularity* it must be. Event that *obscure* package `linux-X.xx.x-x` comes without change log, maybe it is not popular enough?

Answer (score 8):

A better solution would be to use pacolog ([gitlab](https://gitlab.com/protist/pacolog), [aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacolog)), which at least shows you the package commits, e.g.`pacolog -l 3 vim`

Comment: pacolog is in AUR

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asp checkout pkgname` and `git diff ...` to see what happened.

Example:

```
$ asp checkout grub
$ cd grub
$ git log
[...hashes are displayed in the log...]
$ git diff 7d756cac35c2c9e433f7b32dda580cb896e75bbd 860fbf55a3856684bde4cbf79b92fb82f10a68bd
diff --git a/trunk/PKGBUILD b/trunk/PKGBUILD
index 3cb944a..83b9675 100644
--- a/trunk/PKGBUILD
+++ b/trunk/PKGBUILD
@@ -18,8 +18,8 @@ _GRUB_EMU_BUILD="0"
 pkgname='grub'
 pkgdesc='GNU GRand Unified Bootloader (2)'
 epoch=2
-_commit='65bc45963014773e2062ccc63ff34a089d2e352e'
-_pkgver=2.06.r456.g65bc45963
+_commit='e67a551a48192a04ab705fca832d82f850162b64'
+_pkgver=2.06.r499.ge67a551a4
 _unifont_ver='15.0.01'
 pkgver=${_pkgver/-/}
 pkgrel=1
@@ -84,7 +84,6 @@ _configure_options=(
        PACKAGE_VERSION="${epoch}:${pkgver}-${pkgrel}"
        FREETYPE="pkg-config freetype2"
        BUILD_FREETYPE="pkg-config freetype2"
-       --enable-mm-debug
        --enable-nls
        --enable-device-mapper
        --enable-cache-stats
```